# Which Map/Array-Datatype is most suitable for storing and sorting a value pair in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, dictionary, arraylist

In Java I have a dynamic (size: e.g. 5-45) list of value pairs (double, int). I would like to sort the list descending by the first double-value (which is not unique!) and get a sorted list of the second int-values.

For example:

```
input:
0.245  3654
-0.12  7466
0.421  2551
-0.12  1882
0.637  3662
-0.35  5221
0.421  6332

sorted:
0.637  3662
0.421  2551
0.421  6332
0.245  3654
-0.12  7466
-0.12  1882
-0.35  5221
```

And I would like to have a normal ArrayList like: 3662 2551 6332 3654 7466 1882 5221

It doesn't matter if there are some identical double-values; first come, first serve.

I can't use a sorted TreeMap, because the first values (double) aren't unique. What about other HashMaps/LinkedLists/ArrayLists/Arrays?
I tried it manually (in a loop, comparing all values and keeping 2 lists), it worked, but it's very slow. I tried a 2d Array double[][] as well (but their length must be fixed and I got some nullpointers somewhere).

I need: high sorting performance and - if possible - no additional frameworks (like MultiMap eg.) What's the most elegant and fastest way in your opinion?

This was my own beginner-style-way (but this is way too slow!!):

```
pair-value is: e m

for (...kind of a loop...){
    e = method.get(....);
    m = method.get(....);
                            if (eList.isEmpty()) {
                                eList.add(e);
                                rList.add(m);
                            } else {
                                higher = false;
                                for (int i = 0; i < eList.size(); i++) {
                                    if (e >= eList.get(i)) {
                                        eList.add(i, e);
                                        rList.add(i, m);
                                        higher = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!higher) {
                                    eList.add(e);
                                    rList.add(m);
                                }
}
```

Comment: show your HashMaps/LinkedLists/ArrayLists/Arrays tries so that the others could see and gauge how to improve the codes

Comment: Do you really need the whole list sorted or just a portion of the list?
Does the list fit in memory or do you have to stream it from a disk?

Comment: It's basically a **list** of **value pairs**, yes?  So create a `ValuePair` class and make a `List<ValuePair>` to hold them.  Sort descending by the `double` member of the `ValuePair` and ascending by the `int` member?  No problem! You can create a `Comparatot<ValueList>` that imposes whatever sort order you like and use it with `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Yes, I need the whole list sorted. And maximum of entries are about 65, so it should easily fit into the memory. My tries are really beginner-style and a shame to publish. It was just a workaround but I suppose there are mighty Datatypes (Maps/Lists) and their built-in sort-algorhythms should be much more performant. So please show me, if you have some ideas.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: yes, that might be a good idea, I will consider this. Is it fast?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList` (rather than a `LinkedList`) as your `List` implementation and it'll be about as fast as it can possibly  be.

Comment: "maximum of entries are about 65", I think, any sorting for this amount should be very fast. If you speak about 65 millions, may be you see diference.

Comment: Yes, Slava. But this is part of my self-written chess-program! And because of recursion, every nanosecond is very important! So I easily can see, if something is fast or slow.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the most elegant and fastest way in your opinion?

In my opinion, the most elegant and fastest way is using `TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>>`. This would be a [multimap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) using built-in Java features.

From

```
input:
0.245  3654
-0.12  7466
0.421  2551
-0.12  1882
0.637  3662
-0.35  5221
0.421  6332
```

You have `TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>>`

```
0.637 = {3662}
0.421 = {2551,6332}
0.245 = {3654}
-0.12 = {7466,1882}
-0.35 = {5221}
```

Using, for example

```
  for (Pair<Integer, Double> pair : list) {
     Double score= pair.getValue();
     treeMap.putIfAbsent(score, new ArrayList<>());
     treeMap.get(score).add(pair.getKey());
  }
```

Then you can iterate and generate normal ArrayList like: {3662 2551 6332 3654 7466 1882 5221}, for example

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Integer> list : map.values()) {
    result.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this might be an idea as well. Looks good. Could you please show me, how to put the value pairs into the TreeMap. An how can I iterate over it at the end in the simpelst way?

Comment: Yes, but how can I fill the TreeMap?   treeMap.put(0.245,3654)  does not work, because an arrayList<Integer> is expected!

Comment: I add how you can fill

Comment: thank you! It seems to work .. but it's sorted vice versa .... from -0.35 to 0.637 ... can I change that somhow?

Comment: Ah! I found out: TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>> tm = new TreeMap<Double, List<Integer>>(Collections.reverseOrder());   then it's sorted the right way. But this mechanism is very very slow !!! :-(

Comment: Just use Collections.reverse() for ArrayList what you have as result. It should be very fast.

Comment: Or you can multiplay every score to -1, for example instead of  -0.35 to 0.637 save to TreeMap  -0.637... 0.35 and you have correct order (after you can just multiplay to -1 again).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a `Pair` class that holds both `double` and `int` values

```
     class Pair {
        private Double doubleVal;
        private Integer intVal;

        public Pair(Double doubleVal, Integer intVal) {
            this.doubleVal = doubleVal;
            this.intVal = intVal;
        }

        public double getDoubleVal() {
            return doubleVal;
        }

        public int getIntVal() {
            return intVal;
        }
    }
```

And collect the input in a `List<Pair>` as

```
List<Pair> pairs = Arrays
            .asList(new Pair(0.245, 3654), new Pair(-0.12, 7466), /*further elements*/);
```

Now, `Collections.sort()` can be used by providing desired `Comparator` like:

```
Collections.sort(pairs, Comparator.comparingDouble(Pair::getDoubleVal).reversed());
```

which will sort the `pairs` collection based on the `double` values in descending order. As far as the sorting performance is considered, `Collections.sort()` uses [Tim Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (I'm running zulu JDK8. So this sorting algorithm is used as a default) which runs in `O(nlogn)` in worst case.

Form this, a normal array list like {3662 2551 6332 3654 7466 1882 5221} can be obtained as

```
pairs.stream().map(Pair::getIntVal).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thanks - this works as well. But it's much slower than my first try (see in my question) :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the many good suggestions. I tried all of them briefly, but I have to say that my first algorithm is actually the fastest (I was surprised that it is possible to extend a list while iterating over it). It's about **my self-written JAVA chess program**, which I'm very proud of, and I wanted to sort a move list according to the ratings of the individual moves. Then the search is supposed to be faster, or you can possibly cut off unimportant moves.
Now you understand why this code I'm looking for has to be so fast. Because of the recursion and the great depth, every nanosecond is exponentiated. So I could measure that the TreeMap was 30% slower: -o !!
The pair object in connection with the comparator was also about 35% slower.
Hence my question again: can I make my method above (with the manual loop) even faster?